# How to change the language of the Certificate of Completion posted by the DocuSign webhook?

Tags: webhooks, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign Connect webhook to get notifications when an envelope is completed. When I download the Certificate of Completion that is embedded in the webhook call, it's always in English, regardless of the language I have set in my account. If I download the file through the website, it's in Portuguese as it should be.

In the DocuSign API, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) on the *EnvelopeDocuments* resource, you can change the language of the Certificate of Completion by setting the *language* parameter.
Is there a way to do the same in the webhook? Perhaps some option I have to set when creating the envelope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think currently there is no way to set language preference in DS Connect. Ideally DS Connect should be used for notification to your listener, once you receive the subscribed event then you should use API to pull the correct data from DocuSign. If you include documents and CoC in the connect then it impacts bandwidth on your and DS side for every connect messages. So it is better you don't include Document or CoC in the Connect message, and use API to pull the Documents or CoC.